# Unresolved class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService' Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with Firebase in Android studio.
Here is what happen:
In debug mod everything is working fine with follow AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hajora.dndcommerce"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.messaging"
    />
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
 />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"  />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Education"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Splashscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.SingleItemViewEducation" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.SingleItemViewNews" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Main" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Submit" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.News" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Contact" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.About" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutCompany" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutHistory" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutVision" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutPartners" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Ask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" />
    <activity android:name=".Partner" />
</application>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

When i switch to release mode, i get the error:

```
Error:(54) Error: The <service> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
```

So, i then put both services inside  tag and after that i get the error:

```
Unresolved class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService' less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

I cannot figure what is the problem

UPDATE
gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.hajora.dndcommerce'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this image first
[image: Image with error]

check  if Firebase classes are in correct package folder. example if firebase classes are in package 'services' then in manifest service would have `android:name=".services.FirebaseMessagingService"`  then `Unresolved class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService'` error will get solved.

[image]

Comment: I cannot find Firebase classes. I added Firebase via Android Studio tool (automatic), so i didnt put classes by myself

Comment: Is there a template to write the MyFirebaseMessagingService and MyFirebaseInstanceIDService classes referenced at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?

Comment: I guess an example of the templates I am looking for could be at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm.

Comment: Confirmed, this is what I was looking for, from the official documentation: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm.

Answer (score 46):

```
<service
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Giving full path for this lib name com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService fixed this issue.

Comment: You should add android:exported="false" in the service tag as well.

Comment: IDK why android studio docs don't have this as the full string

Answer (score 2):

try to change

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

by

```
 <service
            android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mohammed Farhan, solves my problem. Below is the detailed solution to it.

Here is the solution:

First of all, add below two statements into the manifest file:

```
<!--Everything for notifications part-->
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The reason why we add MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class is to handle creation, updating of registration tokens.

Now, as the error is “Unresolved class”, create two classes in your root package (i.e. mentioned at top of the manifest file) and paste below code in both files:

**1.    MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseService";

public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());



//        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job 
*/ true) {
//                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use 
Firebase Job Dispatcher.
//                scheduleJob();
//            } else {
//                // Handle message within 10 seconds
//                handleNow();
//            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + 
            remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
}
```

**2.    MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 * <p>
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
}
```

And then you are all set. Lemme know if you have any hurdles.

Reference links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your `</application>` tag before `</service>` tag . try below code

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hajora.dndcommerce"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.messaging"
    />
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
 />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"  />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Education"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Splashscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.SingleItemViewEducation" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.SingleItemViewNews" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Main" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Submit" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.News" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Contact" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.About" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutCompany" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutHistory" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutVision" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.AboutPartners" />
    <activity android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.Ask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" />
    <activity android:name=".Partner" />

    <service
        android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.hajora.dndcommerce.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: As i wrote, when i do that i get the error:
Unresolved class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Unresolved class 'MyFirebaseInstanceIDService' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Comment: try to add com.hajora.dndcommerce.MyFirebaseMessagingService in manifest

Comment: And also remove <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/> from activity tag. I updated my answer. check it

Comment: Did like you said but the same problem.

Comment: Could you please check your MyFirebaseMessagingService package name in your class?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in my `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<!-- [START firebase_service] -->
<service
    android:name="com.[myapp].MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_service] -->
```

The text `MyFirebaseMessagingService` that appears in red in the image below should appear in green:

[image]

The red color means that there is something wrong:

[image]

In order to fix it, I created the file `app/src/main/java/com/[myapp]\MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` with the following content:

```
package com.[myapp];
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
}
```

Now in Android Studio, the text that was red changed to green:

[image]